# How to is MySQL's "net_buffer_length" config: viewed and reset?

Tags: mysql, configuration

**Attempt to see the "net_buffer_length" config before resetting it:**

```
mysql> show variables like "net_buffer_length";
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| net_buffer_length | 16384 |
+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Attempt to reset "net_buffer_length" config:**

```
mysql> set global net_buffer_length=1000000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

**Attempt to confirm the "net_buffer_length" config has been reset:**

```
mysql> show variables like "net_buffer_length";
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| net_buffer_length | 16384 |
+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### What's wrong with the commands I'm using that result in the config not updating?

---

- **MySQL Server Version:** 5.1.53-community
- **DATABASE_ENGINE:** INNOdb

---

Questions, feedback, requests -- just comment, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MySQL system variables page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length) on `net_buffer_length`:

```
As of MySQL 5.1.31, the session value of this variable is read only. 
Before 5.1.31, setting the session value is permitted but has no effect.
```